# REST API This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, maven

[image: Application folder structure]I have a spring boot REST API application annotated with @RestController and no html or jsp page. I am testing the API using postman or browser. I am getting below error when I run the application as a spring boot application in eclipse.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Jan 28 17:16:00 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

If I start tomcat normally no errors and it works fine. Checked similar issues in the forum listed are the main issues

1. Use **@RestController** instead of **@Controller**
2. Project folder Structure
3. Thymeleaf dependency.

Checked all these things and verified. Can any one suggest what else I have to verify? Since I don't have a UI page how to deal with it?

Comment: check if you use the correct path when hitting REST API

Comment: I am trying the same path which works for me when I start tomcat separately.

Comment: @Sonka You are correct. I was using wrong path.